# Extracting time series of one pixel from the SMAP soil moisture (soil moisture in %) product

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, pixel, soil

Currently I am writing on my script to extract a time series of SMAP pixel values of the band 'smp', however, my studyarea is rather small and hence the script I found online in this community from AADR

[Extracting Soil moisture value using Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316007/extracting-soil-moisture-value-using-google-earth-engine)

doesn't fit entirely for my question, since it develops on the mean of several pixels.

The script I am working with:

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/marinnvum/DownloadNDVI"),
    geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[16.62138331919588, 48.21312568441956],
          [16.619409213360917, 48.20875013496642],
          [16.62061084299959, 48.2084355385735],
          [16.625159869488847, 48.2077777398707],
          [16.62558902293123, 48.209007530577786],
          [16.624473223981035, 48.21020869299206],
          [16.625288615521562, 48.211409827232984]]]);

// Dataset 

var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP_soil_moisture')
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .filterDate('2018-01-01','2020-09-23');

// Select band -> smp = surface soil moisture (%)

var soilmoisture = imageCollection.select('smp');

// gget scale

var scale = imageCollection.first().projection().nominalScale();

// Take pixel // I know that here is the problem, presumably with ee.Reducer.count() --> I only need one pixel from the time series which has 324 elements

var imageCollection = imageCollection.map(function(image){
  return ee.Image(image.setMulti(image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.count(), geometry, scale)));
});

// Get the images from the dictionary and print it. --> I also have the feeling that aggregate_array doesn't give the relevant data output

var means = imageCollection.aggregate_array('smp');
print('Bodenfeuchte in %', means);

// put in a chart 

print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(imageCollection, geometry, ee.Reducer.count(), 'smp', scale));

Map.centerObject(geometry, 10);
Map.addLayer(soilmoisture, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'soilmoister imageCollection');
```

I replaced `ee.Reducer.count()` already with `ee.Reducer.toList` in order to have the relevant values as a list and then, export them. But eventually my values I am looking for are `NULL`.

Interestingly if I //Create a list of image objects.

```js
var imageList = imageCollection.toList(324);
print('imageList', imageList);
```

I get provided with all relevant images, however, smp or ssm or whatever band you look for, has no values at all if you check them:

```js
print('imageList'+imageList.length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

`ee.Reducer.count()` returns the number of non-null pixels in your region at the scale you request the calculation occur. However, if you want the time series of soil moisture within your study area (`geometry`) you need to take the mean of all soil moisture values within it (and not count the number of pixels with non-null soil moisture). Even if the SMAP pixel is larger than your study area, you can still use `ee.Reducer.mean()` and it will return the pixel's value (mean of something is itself).

[Here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1308ec048aa41870181160027db6b628) is the corrected script will all the unwanted lines commented out. And the desired time series is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks for the help. @kkrao Much appreciated and solves my problems.