# Extract soil moisture for a study area and export as a CSV format with geocoordinates

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am writing a script to extract the time series of soil moisture values from the GLDAS soil moisture data using a shapefile in the Google Earth engine.

However, in the results, I get only 12 elements while I am looking for values from 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31. when I export as a CSV format it only provides the data of Year, Value, Index,  it does not provide the coordinates. My study area has (15 different areas) and it provides the data for 12 areas. That's why I can not understand which value for which area.

Can someone tell me where the problem is with my code in addition to that I want to extract the soil moisture information with the date (months and years) and export it in CSV format with coordinates so that I can identify my location?

Below code, I am using:

```
// Create a chart for SoilMoi100_200cm_inst trend in point 1.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
          .filterBounds(point)
          .filterDate('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')
          .select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst');



var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var start_year = 2012;
var start_date = '2012-01-01';
var end_year = 2012;
var end_date = '2012-12-31';

var years = ee.List.sequence( start_year, end_year);


var byMonthYear =  ee.FeatureCollection(
  years.map(function (y) {
    return months.map(function(m) {
      var w = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .mean();
           
      var pointMean = w.reduceRegion({reducer:ee.Reducer.first(), geometry:point,scale:25000});  
      // set the dictionary as property and cast to an ee.Image, as setMulti returns an ee.Element.
      return ee.Feature(null).set("value",pointMean.get("SoilMoi100_200cm_inst")).set("year",y).set("month",m);
      

    });
  }).flatten()
);


// print the collection, point information
print("feature collection",byMonthYear);


Export.table.toDrive({collection:byMonthYear,description:"csvExport"})

Export.image.toDrive({
image: dataset.select('SoilMoi100_200cm_inst').mean().clip(point),
description: 'smi 2012',
scale: 2500,
region: point


});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Soil moisture value using Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316007/extracting-soil-moisture-value-using-google-earth-engine)

Comment: Not like this. Basically when i export the code as a csv formet, geo coordinate shows the null only shows the soil moisture  value. I want to export the csv file means value of soil moisture  with the coordinated value

Comment: How is your `point` defined? See example https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-filterbounds